# Using update_user_meta to update taxonomy checkbox field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF taxonomy field for my WordPress users which is set as a 'checkbox' type. This contains a list of 'keywords'. I then have a sign up form on the website which allows users to choose their 'keywords'. When they submit that form, a WordPress user account is created for them and I then need to programatically update their ACF keywords list based on the keywords they have selected.

I have tried to do this using the 'update_user_meta' function but that doesn't seem to work. Has anyone managed to work out how to do this?

Below is an example of how I tried using 'update_user_meta':

```
if(isset($_POST['keywords'])) {
    foreach($_POST['keywords'] as $keyword) {
        update_user_meta(1, 'keywords', $keyword);
    }
}
```

^ where $_POST['keywords'] contains an array of keywords that the user has selected

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have researched the issue, see above where I say I tried updating this value using the 'update_user_meta' WordPress function.

Comment: As I said, you need to provide *a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*. We cannot help if we can't see what you have already got in your code so far.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I have now added an example of how I used the update_user_meta WP function, to make this clearer for you

Comment: That's still not enough for us to know what's going wrong. What does "*that doesn't seem to work*" mean? That tells us nothing. Are you getting an error? Is the site breaking? Also, where is this code? Have you used var_dump or done any debugging to confirm that your keywords array is valid? ***Please re-read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)***

Comment: @FluffyKitten What I mean by 'not working' is that the values are not being set for my 'keywords' ACF field when I run my code. So the 'update_user_meta' function is not working. I'm not getting an error, var dump shows $_POST['keywords'] contains my array is it should.

Comment: "*values are not being set for my 'keywords' ACF field *" - how do you know? Are you checking the database or the display? Is it updating the field at all or updating it with the wrong value? And why are you overwriting the value of `keywords` each time in your loop?

Answer (score 0):

All sorted, for anyone that finds this and experiences a similar issue. Turns out  there's an option 'Load value from posts terms' under the taxonomy field type in ACF. This option needs to be unchecked, the correct taxonomy terms are then checked/unchecked on the page/post in WP.